# on-click even intereferes with drop down list in windows phone in app coded using angularjs html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

Have a simple html/angularjs application that   run on every device i.e iphone android windows.
on android and Iphone it works fine but on windows 8 phone there's a glitch.

I have a drop down that gives an option to user to select from zip code and email and based on their selection corresponding input field opens .
now on the drop down also have an on-click event which clears all the error like wrong user id etc from top of the page( which is being called from a directive).
what is expected is that when  the drop down is clicked  the drop down menu should appear as well as the error messages should go away in case there are some.
however in windows when on  first click the error messages go away and then on the next click only the drop down menu is displayed.

SO what i could deduce is that the basic click event functionality is being over written in the directive but then it shouldn't work in any other device too I suppose.

Comment: why do you use the on-focus event? just hook both methodcalls to the onclick event. or are you talking about a select element?

Comment: sorry it was on-click event not on focus . updated the question accordingly.
Actually I have a custom directive in which I remove the error divs using on click event.

Comment: is the directive or the other method that is executed on click somehow preventing the event to bubble? maybe you are returning false or something in a click-handler. not sure how this is handled in angularjs though

Comment: In directive am just calling a function that set's certain flags corresponding to error div's as false.
Am not returning false anywhere in the code for this scenario.
What I can't understand is why this works on other devices and get stuk on WIndows only :(